# Make polyline to show on google map horizontally and zoom it to center coordinate

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am using Google Maps API JavaScript. My use case is I need to plot coordinates (lat, lng) on maps (create markers) and join them through polyline. The co-ordinates will be very close to each other so when I try to plot them, they get hidden behind the first marker. So I find out the center and try to zoom so that all markers will be visible on the map.
I used bounds to find the center but I am not able to zoom it to center co-ordinate. I used    **map.fitBounds(latlng);**  It fits the coordinate on the screen.
But what I want to achieve is to make polyline (connecting all co-ordinate) always horizontal and zoom it to center co-ordinate.

`enter code here`var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

```
for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(temp[i]);
}
var latlng = bounds.getCenter();
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

As the coordinate will always be different, The polyline will be in any direction, but I always want to show it horizontally on the map.
what I get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzu32.png)

what i want to acheive:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcSqo.png)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve something like this by using the following:

1. Use [computeHeading() function of Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#:%7E:text=locations%20with%20the-,computeHeading(),-method%2C%20passing%20it) to get the  angle from your first to your last coordinate on the line. Make sure to add `&libraries=geometry` to your Maps JS script tag.
2. Once you get the heading, you can use the [map.setHeading() function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/webgl/webgl-tilt-rotation#:%7E:text=Call-,setHeading(),-to%20set%20the) to change the angle of your view and after some testings,I can see that you can achieve the horizontal view by subtracting it to 90 degrees.

Here's the [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/r3x6t42y/1/) and code snippet below:

```
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.756795,
      lng: -73.954298
    },
    zoom: 16,
    tilt: 47.5,
    mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
  });


//array of your points
 const markerCoordinates = [
   { lat: 40.758481, lng: -73.958269 },
    { lat:40.754649, lng: -73.949563 },
   
  ];
    
    //creating marker from your points
  for (let i = 0; i < markerCoordinates.length; i++) {
    const marker = markerCoordinates[i];

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position:marker,
      map,
    });
  }
   
   //creating polyline from your points
  const createdPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: markerCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  createdPolyline.setMap(map);
  
  //get the heading(angle) of the first coordinate from the last coordinate
const heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
    markerCoordinates[0],
    markerCoordinates[1]
  )
    
//once you get the heading subtract it by 90 to get a horizontal view
   map.setHeading(heading-90)
}
```